# rails "uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates" on collection_select form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an Items model and a Deliveries model.The deliveries model contains delivery rates, so each Item has one delivery rate. On the Items#show page I want to have a form where a user can select which delivery rate for the Item. I get the following error;

> "uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Deliveries"

```
= form_for [:admin,@item] do |f|
  = f.collection_select :delivery_id, Deliveries.all, :id, :name
  = f.submit
```

I have delivery_id in the items table, and in the items model I have belongs_to :delivery

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Delivery.all`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  = f.collection_select :delivery_id, Deliveries.all, :id, :name


Deliveries.all  should be  => ModelName.all
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an issue of a nested model inside of an engine. Yours may be nested otherwise. I used `EngineName::ModelName.all` rather than `ModelName.all`, so an example would be `Address::Street.all`, and it works.